# Trying to bind to a BASE gridview from within a class

Tags: inheritance, devexpress, aspxgridview, data-binding

So I created a class that would take some data and do some stuff with it and finally spit out a datatable.

I was taking a devex gridview (although I assume asp gridviews might work with the same answer) adding it to the page, instantiating my class (with the id of the data I wanted back) ...then in my pages code behind on page_load, binding the data to the gridview like so:

```
 DashBoard1 = new DashBoard("661", baseUser);

 FFASPxGridView1.DataSource = DashBoard1.dtFinalTable;
 FFASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

This all works fine... however, we have made that gridview into a user control (adding some of our stuff to it) and MY thought was that I would like to surround my dashboard class around the gridview.  So I made my dashboard class a child of the gridview.

```
public class DashBoard : FFASPxGridView
```

Hoping that the final product could be a simple plopping of that control onto the page and an instantiation in the code behind [ i.e. DashBoard1 = new DashBoard("661", baseUser); ] and WHALAH - the finished gridview would show.

I THOUGHT I could accomplish this by binding to my datatable in the final lines of my dashboard class constructor (after I know my final datatable has been created) like so:

```
base.DataSource = dtFinalTable;  //I also tried this.dtFinalTable & this.DataSource, etc.
base.DataBind();
```

When I step through this, the datatable is fine and I get no errors but I get no data to show on my gridview on the finished product.

Additionally, back on the PAGE - I cannot bind the datatable to itself in the page_load event:

```
DashBoard1.DataSource = DashBoard1.dtFinalTable;
DashBoard1.DataBind();
```

Again, NOTHING -- but like I said, if I bind that to just a regular gridview, then I do get data....

Can someone tell me what I am not thinking of?  I have tried to override pre_render and do this in there but that didn't work...im just at a loss.

** Here's a weird behavior (at least to my minunderstanding brain) :  IF I put two of these controls on the page and try and bind one of the datatables to the other, I get data...? **

```
DashBoard2.DataSource = DashBoard1.dtFinalTable;
DashBoard2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have few advices:
You should bind grid in Init event handler. So if you inherit from ASPxGridView, you should have something like this:

```cs
public class DashBoard : FFASPxGridView {
    public Dashboard() {
        Init += InitEventHandler;
    }

    public void InitEventHandler() {
        Datasource = yourDatasource;
        DataBind();
    }
```

You can read more about using Init/Event handlers here: 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18282.aspx

If you create user control it is better to avoid inheritance and wrap containing controls. Create CompositeControl and add your grid to that control Controls collection. More on this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx